# Delegate all method calls on a model to an association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am having an ActiveRecord model with a polymorphic association like this:

```
class Reach < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reachable, :polymorphic => true
end
```

This model acts like a proxy. What I need to do is to forward all method calls on that object to the associated object `:reachable`. I think `delegate` won't help here because I have to explicitly name all the methods I need to delegate. I need something like `delegate :all` to delegate all methods (not `all` method).

Answer (score 25):

**Since Rails 5.1+** you can delegate everything not implemented with `delegate_missing_to :reachable`

Basically, do what you expect.
You could read more on the [Api Doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate_missing_to)

If you are stuck in a previous version then just recommend using the `method_missing` from [@Veraticus answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9914513/8754174), is less performance-wise as mentioned but I think is the more flexible approach.

Answer (score 20):

There are two things you can do here:

1. The slower (performance-wise) but easier method is to use method_missing:

   ```
   class Reach < ActiveRecord::Base

     def method_missing(method, *args)
       return reachable.send(method, *args) if reachable.respond_to?(method)
       super
     end
   end
   ```
2. The faster performing method would be to define each method dynamically that you want to delegate:

   ```
   class Reach < ActiveRecord::Base

     [:all, :my, :methods, :here].each do |m|
       define_method(m) do |*args|
         reachable.send(m, *args)
       end 
     end
   end
   ```

You could even use that method in a more dynamic manner, if you wanted, by taking the Reach class, finding the methods that are defined on it and it alone, and defining only those on Reachable. I would do it by hand though because there are some you probably won't want to include.

Comment: regarding your first aproach. Won't this call the method on the `Reach` object if it exists there?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I think I typed `reach` when I meant `reachable`.

Comment: If you have a list of methods you want to delegate you can just... delegate them as usual.

Answer (score 6):

For Rails, I did the following:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :member
  delegate (Member.new.attributes.keys - User.new.attributes.keys), to: :member
end
```

the `- User.new...` is to not override existing attributes on `User` (e.g., `created_at`)

I'm not sure how this approach would work with polymorphism, however.

Answer (score 4):

I have found a neat way to approach the problem using refinements. There already is a class in the standard library that allows the delegation of every method call to a target object. [`Delegator` and by extension `SimpleDelegator`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html) 
Now there is a way to insert `SimpleDelegator` into your inheritance chain without inheriting from it directly using refinements:

```
def self.include_delegator
  mod = Module.new do
    include refine(SimpleDelegator) { yield if block_given? }
  end
  self.send :include, mod
end
include_delegator
```

Now in order to take advantage of `SimpleDelegator` set the delegation target in an after initialize callback like so:

```
after_initialize do |instance|
  __setobj__(instance.reachable)
end
```

This is equivalent to inheriting directly from SimpleDelegator and setting the delegation in the construction, there is no manual housekeeping of methods to delegate and you can avoid using method missing.